# Installing a library built with cmake on mac os x

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I downloaded the yaml-cpp sources, generated its xcode project, built it, but how do I install the library and its headers, I just want to compile a little console program using g++, I don't know if the xcode project also installed the headers.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Xcode project should have an install target. Alternatively, according to [this](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-November/011910.html) you can do:

```
sudo xcodebuild -target INSTALL
```